# cannot paste words with pictures in ms word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, clipboard, webpage, cut-and-paste

Is there any option that will correct this? I'm pasting my assignment with some pictures in it in ms word 2010 from a webpage but it doesn't seem to be showing the picture that is copied along with the words.
When I try to right click and see the paste options. The only option that I can see is text. Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot paste web page images in Word 2010](https://superuser.com/questions/147557/cannot-paste-web-page-images-in-word-2010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an English version nor Word2010 so the translation might be wrong.

Find a `Paste special` somewhere on your `Edit` menu. Choose `HTML Format`on the menu that shows.

Use that instead of normal paste and you should get images and everything pasted into your word document.