# Cannot paste web page images in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, image-editing, webpage, paste

I am unable to paste web page images into word 2010 - Selecting some text and images on a web page and pasting into word just results in a box on the page. The following question [cannot paste words with pictures in ms word 2010](https://superuser.com/questions/132723/cannot-paste-words-with-pictures-in-ms-word-2010)

says the solution is to use paste special and select HTML. This does not work when I try it.
copying and pasting individual images does not work either.

Comment: "As for 2007 it is workin' perfectly." Not here.

Comment: Do you use the CTRL + V combo to paste or are you right clicking and selecting paste? Also when you copy a picture, make sure you dont click 'Copy Shortcut' and just click 'Copy'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is first to save that image from the web page on you computer. Click on right-button of mouse and select *Save image as ...*. Then open Word and go to Insert->Picture->show the path where you saved that image of the web. And that's it.

Comment: Rather painful don't you think defeats the purpose of cut and paste. Since pasting web pages into word 2007 works OK - It should also work in word 2010.

Comment: Yeah, but it is how to be in this situation. I don't know why it is not workin' in 2010's version. As for 2007 it is workin' perfectly.