# why pictures cannot be paste to word 2010 from chrome

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-word, copy-paste

For example, [this webpage](http://mp.weixin.qq.com/s/Q7ipdKzGQUISWDGAN5vfnA) contains pictures, when I tried to copy & paste into word 2010, the pictures are not pasted, only generated a picture placeholder.

I've tried the trick in https://superuser.com/a/132861/109367 but also to no avail.

However, if I open the webpage in Internet Explorer, copy & paste  works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The website you provided use a custom URL structure that doesn't have the extension in it (eg. ".png" or ".jpg")  ; that's why Word can't recognize it as a picture and thus won't copy it. try to download the images separately and insert them manually into word

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use a snipping tool to grab the photos on the webpage,

Simply open snipping tool and select the area of the page(Photo) and you can paste it in word 2010.

Comment: I'd prefer to keep the text

Comment: @athos, your comment is sort of a non sequitur.  I'm wondering if maybe you misunderstood the solution.  If the image can't be grabbed as a file with the right-click context menu, you can capture it directly off the screen as an image with a clipping tool.  You can then paste the captured image or save the image as a file and paste from the file.